# ASP.NET site recursively HTTP-requesting its own URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis, reentrancy

**Background**: I have an ASP.NET MVC web-application. I want to capture its user-visible HTML content periodically and persist it somewhere so I can track how content evolved over time. I want to be able to pull for example the HTML of homepage as it existed a year ago. This can be done using some kind of crawler that periodically runs through a list of URLs.

**My question**: Is it a good idea to have the website *itself* issue `HttpWebRequest`s to its own URLs? I could launch a `Timer` inside the web-application that downloads and stores one URL per hour.

An alternative architecture would be to have the crawler in an external application like a Windows Service. This would be a much more complicated architecture, though. In this question I'd like not to explore this option because I'm trying to get away with a simpler architecture.

**What can go wrong if an ASP.NET application requests its own URLs using `HttpWebRequest`?**

In pseudo-code:

```
StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), () => {
 var url = "http://localhost/SomePageInTheCurrentW3wpProcess.aspx";
 var data = new WebClient().DownloadString(url); //calling current application
 Persist(data);
});
```

I'm not sure what bad things could happen. I'm thinking of threading an reentrancy problems. I'd have to be careful with distributed deadlocks and such.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to have the website itself issue HttpWebRequests to its own URLs?

No, not at all. Running [`periodic background tasks in an ASP.NET application`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) is a perilous task. Enormously lots of things that are out of your control could get wrong if you go that route. Phil Haack covers most of them in his blog post. Better be advised before going in that direction.

By the way if a managed Windows Service is too complicated architecture for you, a simple Console Application scheduled to run at regular intervals using the [`Windows Scheduler`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) could fit the bill just fine and do the job much better than if you attempt to use ASP.NET for things it wasn't designed for (such as executing periodic background tasks).

Comment: A scheduler task might makes sense, yes. Periodic launching issues aside (I'm familiar with them. It is ok for the crawling task to be randomly interrupted and such), what other issues could arise regarding reentrancy, ...?

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about re-entrancy and don't think issues related to this would occur. There are other, much more serious issues (covered in Phil Haack's blog post) that you should be concerned with if you go that route.

Comment: I've read Phils post an I'm ok with all 3 perils (I know to sustain or mitigate them).

Comment: @usr, great then go ahead. I just wanted to emit a warning so that other people would be aware of the risks.